# UITest failure "upload-symbols crashed in <external symbol>"

Tags: xcode, xcode10, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest, xcode10.3

When I run my UITests they sometimes fail with a weird cause `upload-symbols crashed in <external symbol>`. The only work around I found is to restart Xcode, which helps most of the times, but I'm already tired of doing this.

The UITests scheme is setup correctly and I am able debug the main target during the execution of UITests, so I suppose dsym info is available. The main app doesn't crash and doesn't catch any exception breakpoints when test fails.

The failure happens at random moments of time and during execution of random tests. I haven't seen it happening on CI, which launches UITests from terminal via `fastlane`.

I appreciate any advice.

Xcode 10.3, I'm not sure this was happening on 10.2
MacOS 10.14.6

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely an Xcode bug. I realized, that this crash happens way less likely if I run all tests rather than a specific testcase/test. So I end up disabling all of the tests in the target while developing, except the one I work on and just run them with CMD+U.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I faced with same error:
`crashed in <external symbol>`

I run ui-tests at CI and cause of my error:
Other pipeline delete and reset my current running simulator. 
Also, try find out how to fix this trouble.

I use `fastlane-plugin-test_center`